# How to convert seconds to biggest significative time unit

Tags: javascript, algorithm

What would be the cleanest way to convert an amount of seconds to the biggest unit that is not 0 and then display only the significative unit.

```
Input -> Expected output
1 -> 1s
61 -> 1m
120 -> 2m
3620 -> 1h
86400 -> 1day
```

Comment: What's your approach - how do you imagine you'd accomplish it?

Comment: My current solution is to just brute force it by first dividing the seconds in to hours and flooring the result. If it is 0, I would try to convert to minutes, and so on... But I don't like the idea. Maybe there's some function or smarter way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const units = [
  [1, "s"],
  [60, "m"],
  [60 * 60, "h"],
  [60 * 60 * 24, "day"]
];

function displayTime(seconds) {
  let bestUnit = units[0];
  for(const unit of units) {
    if(seconds >= unit[0]) {
        bestUnit = unit;
    }
  }
  const [divisor, label] = bestUnit;
  return Math.floor(seconds /divisor) + label;
}

console.log(displayTime(1)); // 1s
console.log(displayTime(61)); // 1m
console.log(displayTime(120)); // 2m
console.log(displayTime(3620)); // 1h
console.log(displayTime(86400)); // 1day
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks Peter :)